# Is there a way to compare document library files in my dev and test sites and find out missing files?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have around 300 files missing in my test site during data migration. What is the best possible way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Export both libs to Excel paying extra attention to view settings
2. Merge two Excel sheets' data
3. Sort & apply conditional formatting to color duplicates

This way you'll see that every file that is not present in both locations breaks the color pattern

Comment: Thank you Aziz, but I have not purchased license for Microsoft Excel to export the libraries. All I have is Libre Office. Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Get-detail-report-of-all-b29ea8e2 - this will produce 1 csv file per site. Same idea - get two files, merge them manually (in notepad), pipe to `Select -Unique`

Comment: Unfortunately mine is a office 365 site. Heard it is not possible to include powershell script  in office 365 sites.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice the tag, sorry. Then apps like https://store.office.com/app.aspx?assetid=WA104047994 may be useful, but I know nothing about the quality of 3d-party apps. Be careful. Actually it's easier to run Excel in trial mode in some VM, you know

Comment: Yea I was able to export my library to excel by logging to remote machine which has excel installed. Thank you Aziz.

Comment: My pleasure. Remember to export a view that does not show folders, but shows all files plain side by side. Also, in Excel you can create a new column with `=CONCATENATE([@Path];"/";[@Name])` formula in it to get full urls of each file

Answer (score 2):

1. Create/Switch to a view that shows all records
2. From List tab click on Quick Edit:
   [image]

   Note: In SharePoint 2010 it is available with "Datasheet View" name, also you need to be IE browser to have this option available.
3. Now you can select rows and columns and copy using Ctrl+C.
4. Paste it in any application that supports CSV.

Repeat same for other Library and now you can compare.